# Regex to match ZIP in an address

Tags: regex, street-address

I have address blocks such as

```
10004 South 152nd St. #A
Omaha
Nebraska
68138  United States
```

I am trying to find a RegEX that would match the ZIP code only and not pick up the number in the street.

I tried \d+ but it picks up the first set of numbers in the street. There are about a 1000 addresses like this.

Kindly advise

Thanks

Comment: Lots of us are not Americans. Can you tell in words how you know that `10004` is not a zip, and `68138` is?

Comment: Is the ZIP always next to US? Try `\d+(?=\s+United States)`.

Comment: That works perfectly, Wiktor. Thanks a lot for your prompt help

Comment: Amadan - I was looking to match a preceding or following string to identify the number as a zip, as Wiktor has suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the addresses are U.S. ones, you may match the numbers that are followed with 1+ whitespaces and the *United States* words.

```
\d+(?=\s+United States)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WmHyQx/1)

The `(?=\s+United States)` positive lookahead will require the whitespaces and *United States* after 1+ digits (`\d+`) but won't return that text in the match value. Alternatively, you may use capturing group:

```
(\d+)\s+United States
```

And grab Group 1 value.

It might be a good idea to also make your regex case insensitive with the `(?i)` / `/i` modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wiktor. I am learning RegEX so this is a huge help for me.

Comment: If you have other context markers, you may inlcude them as alternatives: `\d+(?=\s+(?:United States|U\.S\.))` or `(\d+)\s+(?:United States|U\.S\.)` (to also match the digits before `U.S.`).

Comment: Thanks again, Wiktor